# TeamCity Unmet Requirements: VS2017 Exists

Tags: continuous-integration, visual-studio-2017, teamcity

I recently upgraded Visual Studio to 15.6.3 and TeamCity to 2017.2.3. I'm not sure which app is to blame, but I can no longer run builds locally because of "Unmet requirements: VS2017 exists"

[image]

I don't know how to solve this, as Visual Studio does exist on my machine. What can I check to figure out why this is happening or to fix the problem?

Edit: I fortunately have another computer which still had an older version of Visual Studio installed (version 15.3.5). I updated to the latest TeamCity on this machine, transferred my backup file, and the build seems to be working perfectly - it seems to be somehow caused by the latest version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Perhaps, the latest VS does not set something that TeamCity checks for VS2017 parameter? What if  you try to replace that requirement with `VS2017_Path` equals to `real path to devenv.exe on agent`?

Comment: I am not that familiar with TeamCity - can you be more specific about where I would go to change that path?

Comment: If you switch to the 'Agent Requirements' of the build configuration (the way I explained my other comment to the answer below), you'll see the list of requirements defined there. Most likely, there's `VS2017 exits` type of requirement. I was wondering if it can help if you replace it with `VS2017_Path equals [real path to devenv.exe on agent]` type of requirement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other responses helped me track it down, but I thought I'd provide a step-by-step in case anyone else runs into this problem.

First, I had to find the location of my buildAgent.properties file:

1. Click on the **Agents** link at the very top of the page
2. Click on the build agent name (in my case it is **localhost**)
3. Click on the **Agent Parameters** tab
4. Notice the **agent.home.dir** path (mine is **c:\BuildAgent**)
5. Go to **\conf\buildagent.properties** (mine is **c:\BuildAgent\conf\buildagent.properties**

I opened this file in a text editor and added the following:

```
VS2017=15.6.3
VS2017_Path="C\:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe"
```

I then restarted the team city server and build agent services and everything worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you have custom [Agent Requirements](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Agent+Requirements) on your Build Configuration. Check what you have in here:

[image]

Comment: I'm looking on the left side, below the Parameters category, and I don't see an Agent Requirements section https://imgur.com/9HHwyZc Perhaps the UI has changed for this version of TeamCity?

Comment: You are looking at the Project settings, but you should switch to Build Configuration settings. From the screenshot you posted, click on 'General Settings' on the left pane, choose the configuration you need and click 'Agent Requirements' on the left pane as well